# how to set different views for admin and user

Tags: sharepoint, api, view

Hi I am little new to SharePoint. Here is my question

How can we make different views for administrator VS logged in user. For instance I need to display the 
quicklaunch only to admin and not for user. And user should not see site actions tab. 
How can we set this. Please can anyone come up with solution or any blog that we can refer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blog will help with code identifying whether a user is an admin (or even just owner) http://blogs.tamtam.nl/duarte/2008/12/09/Sharepoint+How+To+Verify+If+A+User+Is+Site+Administrator.aspx

You can then create a control that uses this condition to display or hide content. See my blog here for an example:  http://jcapka.blogspot.com/2009/02/handy-hiding-panel.html

You can also use the built in SPSecurityTrimmedControl but it does not provide a means of explicitly checking if a user is an administrator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.aspx